# Rust pattern match assignment: get initial `[T; k]` from `[T; n]`

Tags: arrays, rust, pattern-matching

In Rust, is it possible to use pattern matching to construct a `[T; k]` from the first `k` elements of a `[T; n]`? I am fine with consuming the `[T; n]`. I would like to avoid this:

```rust
// k = 3 here
let [c1, c2, c3, ..] = my_array;
let front = [c1, c2, c3];
```

and instead do something like this (made-up syntax):

```rust
let front: [T; 3];
[..front, ..] = my_array;
// or...
let [..front: [T; 3], ..] = my_array;
// or...
let [front @ [_; 3], ..] = my_array;
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is `T` copy? If not, I don't believe there is a way that is worth it.

Comment: What would the solution be if `T` were `Copy`?

Comment: If `T: Copy`, you can use [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#impl-TryFrom%3C%26%5BT%5D%3E-for-%5BT;+N%5D) to create a `[T; n]` from a `&[T]` of length `n` (which in turn you can get from `my_array`; the bounds-check is required to write down but will be elided).

Comment: If `T` is not copy, you can do that via an allocation, or with unstable APIs, or with unsafe code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` is copy, you can do that easily:

```rust
let front: [T; 3] = my_array[..3].try_into().unwrap();
```

If `T` is not `Copy` but has an inexpensive `Clone`, you can also do it:

```rust
let front: [T; 3] = <&[T; 3]>::try_from(&my_array[..3]).unwrap().clone();
```

If it is not (cloning is expensive or `T` is not `Clone`), you can do it with an allocation:

```rust
let front = my_array.into_iter().take(3).collect::<Vec<T>>();
let front: [T; 3] = front.try_into().unwrap();
```

If an allocation is not acceptable, but you are on nightly, you can use [`Iterator::next_chunk()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.next_chunk):

```rust
#![feature(iter_next_chunk)]

let front: [T; 3] = my_array.into_iter().next_chunk().unwrap();
```

And finally, if nothing is sufficient for you, you can do it using unsafe code (but this should really be the last resort):

```rust
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

pub fn front<T, const N: usize, const M: usize>(arr: [T; N]) -> [T; M] {
    assert!(M <= N);
    let mut arr = ManuallyDrop::new(arr);
    unsafe {
        let result: [T; M] = arr.as_ptr().cast::<[T; M]>().read();
        let rest = arr.as_mut_ptr().add(M);
        let rest_len = N - M;
        let rest = std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut(rest, rest_len);
        rest.drop_in_place();
        result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `next_chunk` looks like the best option overall.